# Bash script: cut the next line in an excel and paste it in new column through command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have an csv file, which I am using in my shell script where my data is like

```
ColumnName1
NameOfAnObject1
100
NameOfAnObject2
200
```

**My requirement is to fetch the data and store it in csv file in below format**

```
ColumnName1         ColumnName2
NameOfAnObject1     100
NameOfAnObject2     200
```

I have tried fetching the data as with below command
`awk '{getline nextLine; print nextLine,$1}' OFS="," file.csv`

But the output that I get is

```
ColumnName1
NameOfAnObject1,100
NameOfAnObject2,200
```

Comment: When you say `I have an excel` - do you actually mean `I have a CSV`? If so, please [edit] your question to state THAT. Regarding `My requirement is to have the data as below` - is that tab-separated output or fixed width fields or something else? Again, [edit] your question to tell us what you need. If you want your output field separator to be a tab, though, then why are you setting `OFS=","`?

Comment: If you _genuinely_ have an Excel file, you will need an external tool which can extract data from it, or convert it to something less horrible, such as a standard CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1{p=$1; sub(/1$/,2,$1)} NR%2{print p, $1} {p=$1}' file
ColumnName1     ColumnName2
NameOfAnObject1 100
NameOfAnObject2 200
```

If you're ever considering using `getline` then please read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline to understand why you probably shouldn't, as in this case.

The above script is just replacing `1` with `2` at the end of the first column header so it'll just reproduce the leading part of the column name rather than hard-coding what we think it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '1s/\([^0-9]*\).*/&\t\12/;1!{/^[A-Z]/{N;s/\n/\t/g}}' input_file
ColumnName1     ColumnName2
NameOfAnObject1 100
NameOfAnObject2 200
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is, say, `file.sample` as below:

```
ColumnName1
NameOfAnObject1
100
NameOfAnObject2
200
```

then you can try this `one-liner` with `sed`:

```sh
sed -i '2i ColumnName2' file.sample && cat file.sample | sed 'N;s/\n/\t/g' > file.csv
```

If you `cat` the `file.csv`, you should get:

```
ColumnName1     ColumnName2
NameOfAnObject1 100
NameOfAnObject2 200
```

`awk` correctly interprets `\t` as field separator, if you do this:

```sh
awk -F"\t" '{ print $1 }' file.csv
```

Outputs:

```
ColumnName1
NameOfAnObject1
NameOfAnObject2
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is *always* formatted as described, you can do this:

(formatted with line breaks for clarity).

```
 awk '
   BEGIN {              # print headers and set separator
       OFS="\t"; 
       print "ColumnName1", "ColumnName2"
         } 
   NR>1{                # skip first line which is header
     getline N;         # read first col, this continues to next line
     print $0, N;       # print the line and data from line before
     N=""}              # ..do not keep the previous line anymore
   '  file.csv
```

```
ColumnName1             ColumnName2
NameOfAnObject1         100
NameOfAnObject2         200
```

The last setting N="" is to avoid having a remaining output of N at the end of the file (if your file ends with a linefeed.)